# Group structure of rotating-square puzzle

Tags: group-theory, permutations, puzzle

Suppose we arrange the numbers $1$ through $6$ at the "vertices" of the shape formed by aligning the sides of two squares, as shown below:

[image]

In this "puzzle," the only moves allowed are rotating the vertices of either square counterclockwise.

I would like to find the group $G$ that represents this puzzle, but I can't figure out how to account for the interaction between the two squares. All I know right now is that $G\subset S_6$, and that $G$ is generated by the permutations $(1254)$ and $(2365)$.

However, I can't figure out how to express $G$ using well-known groups like $S_n$, $A_n$, $D_n$, and $\mathbb Z_n$, the direct product $\times$, and the semidirect product $\rtimes$ (with no corresponding homomorphism specified).

Can someone please show me how to find the group corresponding to this game?

**NOTE:** To someone who is experienced with group theory, this is probably an easy exercise; however, to a novice like myself, this is quite confusing

Comment: What makes you think $G$ is generated by the permutations $(253146)$ and $(136425)$?

Comment: @Servaes Because those are the permutations corresponding to counterclockwise rotations of each of the two squares.

Comment: A counterclockwise rotation on its own has order $4$, but your permutations have order $6$. Rotating the left square maps $1$ to $4$, $4$ to $5$, $5$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$, and leaves $3$ and $6$ fixed. This is represented as $(1\ 4\ 5\ 2)$ in cycle notation.

Comment: Don't you mean $(1\,2\,5\,4)$ and $(2\,3\,6\,5)$.?If so, then consult treatises on Rubik's cube....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh, sorry. I see how that is confusing. My book used two different notations to express permutations; one of them was using $(abcdef)$ to signify that the permutation sends $1\mapsto a$, $2\mapsto b$, and so on. I will change it to the more standard notation in the question; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: These are *clockwise* rotations now.

Comment: @Servaes Well, it should yield the same group, because of closure under inverses, right? Please correct me if that actually results in a different group.

Comment: The group generated by those two permutations is $S_5$.

Comment: @the_fox Could you please explain how you figured that out so quickly? If you explain in an answer, I will be happy to $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$.

Comment: I used GAP. Once you know the answer though, it might not be that difficult to find a proof.

Comment: @the_fox What is GAP?

Comment: https://www.gap-system.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAP shows that the group is in fact isomorphic to $S_5$. A geometric interpretation was requested for what $5$ things are being permuted. Consider the following $5$ sets of edges between the vertices.

$(1,2,5,4)\leftrightarrow(orange,blue,purple,green)$

$(2,3,6,5)\leftrightarrow(red,blue,purple,green)$

[image: S5]

To see that this is all of $S_5$ and not some subgroup, compute some products of elements.

$(orange,blue,purple,green)*(red,blue,purple,green)=(red,purple,orange,blue,green)$

which has order $5$, so the order of the group is a multiple of $5$.

$(orange,blue,purple,green)*(red,blue,purple,green)^{-1}=(red,orange,blue)$

which has order $3$, so the order of the group is a multiple of $3$.

And $(orange,blue,purple,green)$ has order $4$ so the order of the group is a multiple of $4$.

Now the order of the group must be a multiple of $3*4*5=60$, so either $S_5$ or $A_5$. But we have elements of order $4$ in our group, which leaves only $S_5$.

Comment: Wow, amazing! Now all that remains is to prove that $(obpg)$ and $(rbpg)$ generate $S_5$, which should be much easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Frpzzd Updated to show this group is isomorphic to $S_5$ using a similar strategy as the other answer.

Comment: Hold on, doesn't this only show that $S_5$ is a *subgroup* of the group that I'm looking for?

Comment: @Frpzzd A quotient, I think.

Comment: Great, thanks! I wish this question would get a few more views so that your ingenious answer got the attention it deserved. :P

Comment: And the only subgroup of $S_6$ that has $S_5$ as a quotient is $S_5$ itself. I'm not sure if this is a practical answer and of any use for more complicated problems. If you're looking to dig in further, look up the Schreier–Sims algorithm. I think it's what GAP uses anyway, more or less.

Comment: That's a *synthematic total*!

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few tips for identifying the isomorphism type of a small group like this one:

- Determine generators.
- Determine the size of the group.
- Determine the orders of its elements.
- Determine relations between the generators.

Once you have done this, you can consult a list of small groups to get a short list of candidates. You already know that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$, so you can consult a list of subgroups of $S_6$ right away, for example [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=subgroups%20of%20s6&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab).

Here's a start from my end; you have observed $G=\langle(1\ 2\ 5\ 4),(2\ 3\ 6\ 5)\rangle$. Because these two $4$-cycles do not commute, this implies $|G|$ is a multiple of $8$. Moreover, the product
$$(1\ 2\ 5\ 4)(2\ 3\ 6\ 5)=(1\ 2\ 3\ 6\ 4),$$
shows that $G$ has an element of order $5$, so its order is a multiple of $40$. Trying out another combination of the generators yields
$$(1\ 2\ 5\ 4)(2\ 3\ 6\ 5)^2=(1\ 2\ 6\ 5\ 3\ 4),$$
so $|G|$ is a multiple of $6$ as well. The linked document then leaves only three isomorphism types for $G$; either $S_5$, $A_6$ or $S_6$. Because both generators are odd permutations, it cannot be $A_6$. Then it is either $S_5$ or $S_6$, and you could ask whether every permutation of the vertices can be achieved.

More simply, since $G$ contains the $6$-cycle 
$$(1\ 2\ 6\ 5\ 3\ 4)=(3\ 6\ 4\ 5)(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(3\ 5\ 4\ 6),$$
and since $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)$ and any transposition together generate $S_6$, you could ask whether $G$ contains any element of the form $(3\ 6\ 4\ 5)\tau(3\ 5\ 4\ 6)$, where $\tau$ is a transposition.

---

This is clearly a very ad hoc approach, and some familiarity with small groups goes a long way in making the right considerations. Using a software package such as GAP can be a very helpful alternative.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explaining your approach to me; it is very helpful!

Comment: GAP indicates that the group is in fact $S_5$. A $6$ cycle and a transposition will generate $S_6$, not a $6$ cycle and any permutation.

Comment: @Josh B. You are right, corrected.

Comment: @JoshB. Are you sure that a 6-cycle and *any* transposition will generate $S_6$? What about $(126534)$ and $(23)$?

Comment: @Frpzzd You have a point; these together do not generate $S_6$. I will edit soon. The point being that $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)$ and any transposition generate $S_n$, so conjugating both by $(3\ 6\ 4\ 5)$ yields another pair of generators $(1\ 2\ 6\ 5\ 3\ 4)$ and $(a\ b)$ for some $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Servaes Also, how can I interpret the fact that the group is $S_5$? What $5$ things are being permuted, exactly?

Comment: @Frpzzd That is a very good question which I have considered myself, but have not been able to answer (apart from a contrived abstract answer that is simply a restatement of which subgroup of $S_6$ it is). A geometric interpretation would be nice, if it exists. Perhaps this is worthy of another question. Also, an interesting related question is "what remains invariant?".

Comment: @Servaes My ultimate goal is to be able to determine the group structures for constructions like this without the aid of a computer or online database of groups, hence the importance of a geometric interpretation.

Comment: These two cycles leave $3$ fixed, so they cannot generate all of $S_5$. In fact I don't see what the group structure is now; in this way $S_5$ does not act on the vertices $1$ through $5$.

Comment: @Frpzzd You are right about the cycles and transpositions. I have a geometric interpretation, but I would need to make some pictures.

Comment: @Frpzzd $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,...,n)$ will generate $S_n$. Also, an n cycle and any transposition will generate $S_n$ if $n$ is prime.